# How to add Timezone formfield in JSP

Tags: html, jsp

I have the following code to add timezone form field in JSP as a dropdown list for the user to select.

```
<select name="DropDownTimezone" id="DropDownTimezone">
      <option value="-12.0">(GMT -12:00) Eniwetok, Kwajalein</option>
      <option value="-11.0">(GMT -11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
      <option value="-10.0">(GMT -10:00) Hawaii</option>
      <option value="-9.0">(GMT -9:00) Alaska</option>
      <option value="-8.0">(GMT -8:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>
      <option value="-7.0">(GMT -7:00) Mountain Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>
      <option value="-6.0">(GMT -6:00) Central Time (US &amp; Canada), Mexico City</option>
      <option value="-5.0">(GMT -5:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada), Bogota, Lima</option>
      <option value="-4.0">(GMT -4:00) Atlantic Time (Canada), Caracas, La Paz</option>
      <option value="-3.5">(GMT -3:30) Newfoundland</option>
      <option value="-3.0">(GMT -3:00) Brazil, Buenos Aires, Georgetown</option>
      <option value="-2.0">(GMT -2:00) Mid-Atlantic</option>
      <option value="-1.0">(GMT -1:00 hour) Azores, Cape Verde Islands</option>
      <option value="0.0">(GMT) Western Europe Time, London, Lisbon, Casablanca</option>
      <option value="1.0">(GMT +1:00 hour) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris</option>
      <option value="2.0">(GMT +2:00) Kaliningrad, South Africa</option>
      <option value="3.0">(GMT +3:00) Baghdad, Riyadh, Moscow, St. Petersburg</option>
      <option value="3.5">(GMT +3:30) Tehran</option>
      <option value="4.0">(GMT +4:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat, Baku, Tbilisi</option>
      <option value="4.5">(GMT +4:30) Kabul</option>
      <option value="5.0">(GMT +5:00) Ekaterinburg, Islamabad, Karachi, Tashkent</option>
      <option value="5.5">(GMT +5:30) Bombay, Calcutta, Madras, New Delhi</option>
      <option value="5.75">(GMT +5:45) Kathmandu</option>
      <option value="6.0">(GMT +6:00) Almaty, Dhaka, Colombo</option>
      <option value="7.0">(GMT +7:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta</option>
      <option value="8.0">(GMT +8:00) Beijing, Perth, Singapore, Hong Kong</option>
      <option value="9.0">(GMT +9:00) Tokyo, Seoul, Osaka, Sapporo, Yakutsk</option>
      <option value="9.5">(GMT +9:30) Adelaide, Darwin</option>
      <option value="10.0">(GMT +10:00) Eastern Australia, Guam, Vladivostok</option>
      <option value="11.0">(GMT +11:00) Magadan, Solomon Islands, New Caledonia</option>
      <option value="12.0">(GMT +12:00) Auckland, Wellington, Fiji, Kamchatka</option>
</select>
```

Is there any simple way to add timezone formfield other than this code? I mean by using any simple method or JQuery something?

Comment: Are you using this code on a lot of different JSP pages?

Comment: no. Only on one page as of now. I havn't added it yet. If there is no other option, I have to add this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any simple way to add timezone formfield other than this code? I mean by using any simple method or JQuery something?

Your approach is as easy as it can be: You know exactly, which values are displayed, which values are sent to the server on submit, which order the values have etc. You approach will work without Javascript as well, and you have not to rely on any external library.

Since you are using this code on only one page, you have no problem with duplicate code in your pages. So, my recommondation is, keep this code, it is the simplest solution, and you will be fine.

However, once you use this code on different pages, you can use a [custom JSP tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm) instead of copying it everytime.

Comment: Ok. Thankyou! Yeah only for one page this is enough. But I thought there will be simple methods. :)

Answer (score 0):

well, you can always populate your select field from json data and use this plugin: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ .. but.. it's not simpler :)